# How does `Depends on` and `Selected by` work in Kconfig when they conflict

Tags: u-boot, kbuild

To understand how SPL (secondary boot loader), I tried (in u-boot v2021.10)

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-none-elf- vexpress_ca9x4_defconfig
```

and

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-none-elf- vexpress_ca9x4_defconfig
```

I searched for SPL_OS_BOOT, which I need to test the SPL falcon mode. But it appears it is not enabled by default for this board.
[image]

So first I need to set CONFIG_SPL=y, but when I search for SPL, it shows this.
[image]

I can't clearly understand it here.
Does `Depends on: ARM [=y] && ARCH_STM32MP [=n]` mean I should set the `ARCH_STM32MP=y`?
and if I add a `Selected by` condition, should it still meet the `Depends on` condition above?
I ask it because SPL should be avaiable for many boards but having ARCH_STM32MP, -- a very specific architecture condition --, in the `Depends on` list looks weird.

Comment: As a general note, `ARCH=` is wrong in U-Boot and actively harmful in a number of cases (such as building aarch64 platforms).

Comment: scripts/decodecode is the one tool in U-Boot that requires ARCH to be set on ARM platforms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kconfig in general can be difficult to follow (and a few things in how we use it in U-Boot need to be cleaned up as it makes things harder still to follow).  It's often best to look at the Kconfig files directly, to better understand things.  In this case as you've noted, `SPL_OS_BOOT` depends on `SPL` and if we look in *common/spl/Kconfig* we see:

```
config SPL
        bool
        depends on SUPPORT_SPL
        prompt "Enable SPL"
        help
          If you want to build SPL as well as the normal image, say Y.
```

which hints at the real problem you're facing, vexpress_ca9x4 does not support SPL.  That's what the long list of things you were trying to figure out was showing, the places where `SUPPORT_SPL` is set.

Comment: Thank you. I added select SUPPORT_SPL and select SPl for the target select. I'm trying to forcibly make SPL falcon mode work on our simple board. I wish there were a 'getting started' document in the u-boot docs.